# How to redirect to another php script using jQuery/AJAX

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to use Ajax/jquery to be able to redirect to another php script to perform a command in the script.

I have a jquery/ajax code function below, my question is that is the jquery.ajax function correct in order to redirect to the "cancelimage.php" script?

```
$(imageuploadform).find(".imageCancel").on("click", function(event) {
    $('.upload_target_image').get(0).contentwindow
    $("iframe[name='upload_target_image']").attr("src", "javascript:'<html></html>'");
    jQuery.ajax("cancelimage.php");
    return stopImageUpload(2);
});​
```

Comment: when you tried , what is the error you got ?

Comment: I didn't get an error, it is just that it is not performing the mysqli tasks I have in the cancelimage.php page. I am sure that mysqli commands are correct which makes me believe that the ajax is not redirecting to the cancelimage.php page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is what you want , but for a complete redirect

```
 Window.location.href='cancelimage.php'
```

But if your looking for an ajax success/fail type response from your code

```
 $.ajax{(
 url:'cancelimage.php',
 data: 'yourData', //either serialized from form submit or created on the fly
 Success: function(yourResponse){ //if Conditions met
 },
 Error: function(request){ alert(request.responseText);}
 )};
```

Then its a matter of updating your cancelimage.php script to return boolean true/false, a JSON object using json_encode or whatever youd like